# Excel doesn't recognise dates

Tags: excel, date, format, date-formatting

I would like to write dates in Excel in the form of a 6 digit code with the first 4 digits being the year and the last two being the month. For ex, 01/02/2013 should be 201302. (Days are to be ignored) However, even after I formatted the cells to yyyymm. It keeps showing a different number in the cell with the formula bar showing the date format as dd/mm/yyyy. For ex. 201301 is entered but excel automatically converts it to 245102 with the date at the formula bar showing 20/02/2451. How do I get excel to recognise my custom input directly in the 6 digit code as I need to perform further calculations on the dates? Looked up for over an hour for a solution.

Comment: a custom number match does not change the value underneath.  so When you enter the `201301` excel assumes you are putting in the datevalue which is a whole number of days since 1/1/1900.  so 201,301 days since 1/1/1900 is 20/2/2451.  If you do not want to do anything with the dates later you can make the column a non date format, like number or text.  If you want to make them actual dates then you will need a worksheet_change event in vba to deal with the value change.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your cell with the date and go to

Data -> Text To Columns. Click on it and choose Delimited -> Next -> Next -> choose the Date Radiobox and pick YMD -> Finish.

After that make a right click on the cell. Format Cells -> Number Tab -> Category Custom and type YYYYMM and click ok.